How to find lattice constant (Si/GaAs/any material) at finite temperature using Car-Parrinello Molecular Dynamics (CPMD)?
Would anyone please guide me stepwise how can I find lattice parameters of a material, for example: Si, GaAs, at a finite temperature using Car-Parrinello Molecular Dynamics (CPMD)?
Thank you

Does this answer your question? Visualize variation of lattice parameters with temperature after MD

Thank you for sharing it. In the first plot, lattice constant vs Temperature has been drawn there and exactly I want to do this using CPMD. In the mention post, he didn't describe the procedure. I just want to see any example of NPT ensemble done by CPMD, so that I can get some idea and work on it. Thank you again.

For example, I have a structural data of GaAs/Si at 0 K. I will use it to find out optical properties (Phonon-assisted). But when I apply temperature effect (e.g 900 K), I need to find out the structural information on that temperature (@900 K). Once I know the structural information, I will find out the corresponding optical properties (Phonon-assisted) on that temperature via Quantum Espresso software.

It is as simple as "run AIMD with the code of your choice, extract the box-vectors, and calculate the lattice parameters from those". If you mean you want an example of how to run AIMD, check the quantum espresso examples directories, e.g. $ROOT/CPV/examples

Thank you, I am going to follow these examples first.

Great! Note, CPMD is a particular method for MD. It is also possible to do the more traditional AIMD by simply calculating forces from scratch at every MD timestep. This is implemented in the pw package. You can find examples in the $ROOT/PW/examples directory.
